# MassTransit throws System.MissingMethodException

Tags: asp.net-core, masstransit

I have a problem in my MassTransit its throwing me exception - `System.MissingMethodException` 
My code is:

```
TimeSpan requestTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(60);
CRUDWhiteBlackListRequest crudWhiteBlackListRequest = new CRUDWhiteBlackListRequest()
{
  CorrelationId = Guid.NewGuid(),
  Operation = operation,
  FileHashSHA256 = fileHashSHA256,
  WhiteBlackRecord = whiteBlackList
};
IRequestClient<CRUDWhiteBlackListRequest, CRUDWhiteBlackListResponse> client = new MessageRequestClient<CRUDWhiteBlackListRequest, CRUDWhiteBlackListResponse>(_bus, _filePolicyEvaluationUri, requestTimeout);
CRUDWhiteBlackListResponse result = await client.Request(crudWhiteBlackListRequest);
return result;
```

The code catch exception in line: `CRUDWhiteBlackListResponse result = await client.Request(crudWhiteBlackListRequest);`

The message is: `Method not found: 'System.Net.Mime.ContentType MassTransit.Context.BaseSendContext`1.get_ContentType()'.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved it by update all my micro services MassTransit package versions that all services will have same version.